# How to interpret a GenomeScope plot?

Tags: ngs, genome, sequence-annotation, illumina, genome-sequencing

I am working on a new sponge genome and I have produced the genomescope plot from the 21-mer kmer frequencies. I have hard time interpreting the plot. Can someone please help me?
Thank you.[image]

Comment: Hi @MudithEkanayake IMO the question has been answered. Please ask via comments if you're not clear about the answer. Do remember to upvote/accept when you're happy with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the numbers shown above the plot, and the appearance of the curve, this looks like reads from a diploid genome approximately 113Mb in length that was sequenced at around 174X coverage.